# How to configure HandleHttpRequest on Apache Nifi to work with multiple nodes?

Tags: java, apache, apache-nifi

I have created a HandleHttpRequest processor on Apache Nifi which has a REST endpoint that takes data and stores in DB. So when I send a REST request to this endpoint, I am able to receive the data and store it in DB.

I have 3 nodes of Apache Nifi configured using zookeeper running on 3 different VMs. Assuming the endpoint is running on IP and Port 125.120.122.120:9092, when I send a request to that IP and port, I am able to receive the data. However, let's say the other two Nifi nodes are running on machines 125.120.122.121, 125.120.122.122, if I send a request to 125.120.122.121:9092 or 125.120.122.122:9092, I am unable to receive the data. But I can see HandleHttpRequest processor running on all the 3 nodes.

Can someone help me with this? I want 125.120.122.121:9092 and 125.120.122.122:9092 to handle the request like 125.120.122.120:9092 does.

Comment: Did you configure the property `Hostname` in `HandleHttpRequest` with some value or leave it empty?

Comment: @SivaprasannaSethuraman I left it empty. I didn't configure that property.